# Is it possible to have outlook aggregate multiple public folder hierarchies?

Tags: exchange, outlook

I wonder if it is possible for outlook to aggregate multiple public folder hierarchies ? When I look at the [xml schema for autodiscover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202398(v=exchg.80).aspx) the `SmtpAddress`element under the `PublicFolderInformation` seems to allow multiple addresses.

Is it possible to have the hierarchy split between two primary public folder mailboxes and have outlook connect to both ?

Comment: Same Exchange organization? If so, multiple public folder mailboxes should only be a result of mailbox size management, and should still be part of the same PF structure for that organization, right?

Comment: @SturdyErde yes same organization. I would like to know how the autodiscover response for such a setup would look like, or if it is possible.

Comment: Looping back to this question to see if you have figured it out. I also think I have better understood your question: are you basically looking to have multiple root public folders, or do you mean something entirely different with the phrase "multiple public folder hierarchies"?